# Radio Buttons - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created a Power Shell form which allows me to input users into a text box and mark whether I want to add/remove them from a particular group.  Now, I have grouped all of these into a single group.

How can I still group my radio buttons, but allow for multi select?

For example,

- In input box 1, I want to add a user.
- In input box 2, I want to remove the user,
- In input box 3, I want to add a user.

So I'm not wanting to select Add and Remove for the same input box, just one selection per input box.  Hope that makes sense and all help is appreciated!

[image: PowerShell Form]

Comment: So, you want a checkbox?

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, you answered part of my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krisz's answer is right, you need to group them. When they all sit on the form they are all in one big group and only one can be clicked.

here is a snippit of code I have where I did this as part of a sample, hope it helps:

```
$MyGroupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$MyGroupBox.Location = '195,66'
$MyGroupBox.size = '133,122'
$MyGroupBox.text = "Group of radios"

$MyGroupBox.Controls.AddRange(@($GroupRadiobutton1,$GroupRadioButton2,$GroupRadioButton3))
$form.controls.add($MyGroupBox)
```

Answer (score 3):

Put each two radio buttons for a group in a container object like a Panel or a GroupBox. That will automatically group them together.